# "for line in file" returns letters instead of lines (python)

Tags: python, for-loop

Sometimes when I use a for loop to iterate through lines of a file, I get each letter separately instead of each line. Can someone explain why that is?

Comment: Can you show the file you're reading and the code you're using to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [Iterator Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter)

```
for a in something:
    pass
```

If `something`s type is a itereable, `a` will take all values of your iterable in turn. What exactly `a` becomes is hidden inside the `__iter__(self):` implementation of the object you are iterating over (afaik).

- If you iterate over a `list`, it will present you with all values in turns.
- If you iterate over a `dict`, it will present you with all `dict.keys()` in turns.
- If you iterate over a `string`, it will present you each character in turn.

Generators and sequences also provide iterating over, see [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python) and [Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

If you iterate over a file, you will get (textfile, not binary) it line by line, unless you call other methods on the file first ():

Demodata:

```
with open("f.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""Some Text
Some text after a newline.
More text in a new line.""")
```

Iterate of file using it as iterable:

```
with open("f.txt","r") as r:
    for c in r: # returns each single line including \n (thats the way next() of file works
        print (c) # appends another \n due to default end='\n' 
print("-"*30)
```

Output:

```
Some Text

Some text after a newline.

More text in a new line.
------------------------------
```

---

Iterate over file.read():

```
with open("f.txt","r") as r:
    t = r.read() # returns a single string of the whole files content
    for c in t:  # you iterate characterwise over a string!
        print (c)
print("-"*30)
```

Output:

```
S
o
m
e

[... snipped ...]

l
i
n
e
.
------------------------------
```

---

Iterate over file using readline():

```
with open("f.txt","r") as r:
    for c in r.readline(): # returns only the first line as string and iterates over this string
        print (c)          # the other lines are omitted!
print("-"*30)
```

Output:

```
S
o
m
e

T
e
x
t

------------------------------
```

---

Iterate over file using readlines():

```
with open("f.txt","r") as r:
    for c in r.readlines(): # returns a list of strings
        print (c)  # appends another \n due to default end='\n' 
print("-"*30)
```

Output:

```
Some Text

Some text after a newline.

More text in a new line.
------------------------------
```

---

Iterage over binary file:

```
with open("f.bin","wb") as f:
    f.write(b"294827523")
    f.write(b"2927523")
    f.write(b"-27523")
    f.write(b"\n-27523")

with open("f.bin","rb") as r:
    for b in r:
        print (b)
```

Output:

```
b'2948275232927523-27523\n'
b'-27523'
```